# What is the reason of using underscore in this case

Tags: go

[I have the following code snippet](https://github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/blob/master/example/main.go)

```
type tracingHandler struct {
    handler http.Handler
}

var _ http.Handler = &tracingHandler{}
```

What is the reason for declaring a variable which is not used?

Answer (score 2):

It's a compile time check by the package developer. The package will not compile if `tracingHandler` does not implement the `http.Handler` interface.

I assume this is a middleware http package - so the developer is ensuring their handler follows the standard library's [http.Handler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) interface:

```
type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)
}
```

So, to compile, the `tracingHandler` type must have a method with a pointer receiver - since the assignment used `&tracingHandler{}` - and the method signature should look like this:

```
func (h * tracingHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // ...
}
```

Using the blank identifier `_` ensures the assignment is never stored and thus is a NOP. So the line is purely a build integrity check.